# can I group the servers inside known_hosts file?

Tags: known-hosts

I was wondering if there is a way to group servers inside the known_hosts file

something like this:

```
[AWS]
11.xx.x.1 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 xxxx=
11.xx.x.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 yyyy=
11.xx.x.3 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 zzzz=

[ALIBABA]
12.xx.x.1 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 1321=
12.xx.x.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 1244=
12.xx.x.3 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 2412=

[AZURE]
10.xx.x.1 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 xxxx=
10.xx.x.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 yyyy=
10.xx.x.3 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 zzzz=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only using `#` comments. The format does not have INI-style [sections].

For example:

```
# AWS
11.xx.x.1 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 xxxx=
11.xx.x.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 yyyy=
11.xx.x.3 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 zzzz=

# Alibaba
12.xx.x.1 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 1321=
12.xx.x.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 1244=
12.xx.x.3 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 2412=

# Azure
10.xx.x.1 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 xxxx=
10.xx.x.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 yyyy=
10.xx.x.3 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 zzzz=
```

New entries *will not* automatically go to the correct group; the client always just appends them at the end (so put a separate `# Misc` section there).

---

Alternative: You can have *multiple* known_hosts files, selecting one based on host in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host 11.xx.x.*
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.aws

Host 12.xx.x.*
    UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.alibaba
```

This will allow the ssh client to automatically write new entries into the correct file.